# how to store the values into a single variable

Tags: matlab

I have created a X-by-Y matrix . Multiplies each element of the matrix  with the X(length) and Y(breadth) which generates a rectangular matrix(This is done in order to plot the points throughout the length and breadth of the matrix).
But I am not able to store all the values generated from the for loop into y  and x.

1) Kindly please tell me how to store the values into a single variable in the below program

2) And I am not able to plot two unequal dimensions  which are generated after the operations are performed in the below program.

```
X=input('enter the dimension of the matrix:');
Y=input('enter the dimension of the matrix:');    

a=rand(X,Y)

for i=1:X
  x=a(i,:)
  px=x.*X
end

for j=1:Y
  y=a(:,j)
  py=y.*Y
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of MATLAB functions that could be used to get a matrix with random values.
`randi(maxi, X, Y)` looks like the one more useful here.
Get ride of the for loops:

```
X=input('enter the dimension of the matrix:');
Y=input('enter the dimension of the matrix:');    
maxi = 100;
a=randi(maxi,X,Y);
```

and if you want to visualize it do:

```
imagesc(a);
```

Comment: I would like to create a rectangular matrix where the points are displayed randomly.But when i use rand() function the points are concentrated between 0 and 1 so in order to plot the points throughout the rectangle I am multiplying with the length and breadth of the rectangle.But the main problem is that I want to plot all the values of the matrix after multiplication, which is giving error

Comment: You can use `randi(maxi, x, y)`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to plot two unequal vectors?

Comment: What do you mean by plot? You want a scatter plot? or you want an image? or line ...

Comment: suppose x=[1 2 3;3 4 5],y=[1 2;4 5]..how to plot(as points in the graph)

Comment: Still not clear what type of graph? What are the points here? is `a=[1 2];` a point? is this a mean and errorbars graph? scatter plot? histogram?

Comment: x=[1 2 3;3 4 5] is a matrix with 2 rows and 3 col and y is another matrix with 2 rows and 2 col ..I need to plot( using plot()) the values of matrices X and Y which is giving an error coz the dimensions are unequal...Is there any other way to plot them.

Comment: @RJ'th what I dont understand is What you expect to see in the plot?

Comment: Or try this one `plot([x, y])'`

Comment: Thanks Ali for the suggestion...Very grateful to you

Comment: @Ali: Can you please update your answer? As-is, it is more of a comment.

Comment: @Jonas I edited the answer and I believe it actually answers the question.

Comment: @Ali: Thanks. It's better if the information is in the answer rather than in the commentaries. +1 btw.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration of your "for" loops overwrites x, px, y, and py with new values, so it drops all of the old values.  To be honest, I wouldn't even bother with the for loops.  Assuming that what you really need is px and py, I would just do this-

```
px = a * X;
py = a * Y;
```